nmcli: How to re-perform IPv6 router solicitation?
This is a Raspberry Pi running 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS bookworm (debian 12.5).
Sometimes when I boot I find that IPv6 hasn't successfully been set up. The local network has an IPv6 capable border router and the IPv6 networking on the local network is quite ordinary. If I reboot the pi, this will usually fix it, but is there an nmcli invocation that will ask NetworkManager to repeat the router solicitation? Or even to just re-perform the WiFi connection procedure, DHCP and rtsol?

Run rdisc6, from the "ndisc6" package. NetworkManager will handle the resulting Advertisement in the same way as scheduled unsolicited RAs.
Alternatively, use nmcli con up <name> to completely reconnect the Wi-Fi configuration.
